# My Divs are overlapping in Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to BootStrap 3 and am having problems with my divs overlapping. I'm probably missing something simple, but can't seem to find the problem. Here is the html.

You can also find a working copy of what I am trying to do in Bootstrap at wibberding.info/SolarTime.

Thanks for any help you can give.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>  
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Solar Time</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>

<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="container clearfix">
<h1 id="clock">Solar Time</h1>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">
<p>This web app allows you to find Solar Time in two ways:</p>
<p> 1. Find Solar Time by reading the location data from your device. You will have to have this turned on. </p>
<p> 2. By entering a longitude. You can find the longitude of your zipcode <a href="https://www.zipinfo.com/search/zipcode.htm" target="_blank">here</a>.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<form id="form">
<input id="device" type="radio" name="locationData" value="device" checked onchange="solarTime.checkLocationMethod()">
<label for="device">Use my device location.</label><br>

<input id="latLong" type="radio" name="locationData" value="latLong" onchange="solarTime.checkLocationMethod()">
<label for="latLong">Enter Longitude</label>
<input type="text"  size="10" maxlength="30" id="longitude" onFocus="solarTime.changeToLong()"></input> (Enter postive longitude for East and negative for West. All of the United States is negative.) <br>

<input type="button" onclick="solarTime.checkLocationMethod()" value="Find Solar Time" />
</form>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I took a quick look, what divs in particular are you having issues with?

Comment: Your form elements are probably exceeding the widths of your divisions. Try wrapping them in bs' form containers (ie .form-groups). (though it's hard to tell from just looking at this) http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: On closer inspection it looks like my rows are overlapping each other too. Everything wants to render at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like I missed a closing DIV tag. It now works :-) Thank you everyone for your help . . .